# spl_autoload_register() with multiple folders

Tags: php, autoload

I'm using the below snippet to autoload classes from several folders:

```
// Check if the autoload configuration file exists
if(is_file("configuration/autoload")) {
    // Extract the listed folders from the configuration file
    $folders = explode("\n", file_get_contents("configuration/autoload"));
    // Prepend the base path to the extracted folder paths
    array_unshift($folders, get_include_path());
    // Configure the folders in which to attempt class autoloading
    set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $folders));
    // Configure the file extensions that should be autoloaded
    spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
    // Administer the attempt to autoload classes
    spl_autoload_register();
}
```

The several folders are listed in a file like so:

```
core/utility
core/factory
core/modules
core/classes
core/classes/form
core/classes/form/fields
frontend
```

It works like charm locally, but I can't get it to work on my online server (I did CHMOD all files & folders involved). I guess things are going wrong while setting the include paths, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Most often when I hear that autoloading breaks on the server, it's because servers are often running linux with a case-sensitive file-system. OS X and Windows are not case-sensitive by default.

So the problem may simply be that you're trying to autoload a class with a different casing than the filename.

Comment: @Evert I do apply the same case formatting for both classes and their filenames

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend to create your own autoload function i.e. my_autoloader. This way you have complete control for the folder handling.

```
function my_autoloader($className)
{
    $parts = explode('\\', $className); //split out namespaces
    $classname = strtolower(end($parts)); //get classname case insensitive (just my choice)

        //TODO: Your Folder handling which returns classfile

    require_once($loadFile); 
}
spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__ . '\my_autoloader');
```

Remember to handle different namespaces

Comment: It actually boils down to this: I'm setting my include paths dynamically because I **don't** want to have "Zend-like" classnames like Framework_Controller_SomeClass (like Magento does too apparantly). Perhaps this is too much to ask, but as it's working like charm locally - I figure I'm just a small step away from achieving my goal

Comment: I don't use Zend-like classnames in my code. I just traverse the folders using `if(file_exists($current_folder . "\" . $classname . ".php")`... AND If you are sure you never use namespaces in the code you also can ignore the part handeling the namespace structure in PHP

Answer (score 0):

This is how Magento eCommerce does it:

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if (defined('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
        $classFile = $class.'.php';
    } else {
        $classFile = uc_words($class, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).'.php';
    }

    include($classFile);
}
```

Then you would have the following structure:

```
class Company_Category_Class{}
```

And the following stricture (assuming you have "lib" in your include path):

```
./lib/Company/Category/Class.php
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: The thing is, I'm trying to get by without having to apply a certain hierarchy to my classnames. I know it can be done and as it's working locally, I can't be too far off!

Comment: So just slightly modify it by doing something like ./lib/Company_Category_Class.php ?